# non 'ascii' characters in requests response

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-requests

I use requests to get json data from API source

```
req = requests.get('url')
context = json.loads(req.text)
print(context)
```

return the error

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /view/
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 26018-26019: ordinal not in range(128)
Unicode error hint

The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: OLYURÃ‰THANE
```

I checked `req.text` and didn't find there non-ascii characters. It appeards after `json.loads(..)`

Comment: The symbol `Ã‰` is not a ascii sysmbol. [Acii character list](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: I know. how to ignore it or sort of

Comment: you can catch the exception and ignore it or check the ord() of each character of the string to be less than 128, and ignore these character if you still need to process the text.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
request_txt = req.text.encode('utf-8')
context = json.loads(request_txt)
```

You need to apply `.encode('utf-8')` to the string which is throwing this error.

Answer (score 1):

Try similar like [@Maninder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2212539/maninder-singh) wrote, but instead of `encode()` use `decode()`

```
context = json.loads(req.text.decode("utf8"))
```